# How to implement File Tree Walk safely (C language)

Tags: c, linux

I tried this code on Fedora, but got `No such file or directory` and `Permission denied` errors.

How to handle errors and continue scanning file system?

ftw() crushes if something goes wrong. How to skip bad entries?

ftw() starts from path `/`.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ftw.h>
#include <time.h>

FILE * output;

static int display_info(const char * fpath, const struct stat * st, int tflag)
{
    switch(tflag){
        case FTW_F://ok, file
            break;
        case FTW_D://ok, directory
            break;
        case FTW_SL://symlink
            return -1;
        case FTW_NS://stat failed
            return -1;
        case FTW_DNR://read failed
            return -1;
    }
    fprintf(output, fpath);
    fprintf(output, "\n");
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    time_t t0;
    time(&t0);
    output = fopen("/home/sad/output.txt", "w");
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Usage: %s [path]\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    if(ftw(argv[1], display_info, 99) == -1){
        perror("???ftw()");
        return -1;
    }
    fclose(output);
    time_t t1;
    time(&t1);
    printf("%.3f seconds\n", difftime(t1, t0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't return -1 if you want processing to continue.  It starts scanning where you tell it.

Comment: When I return 0 another error appears: Operation not permitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is returning -1 whenever a path passed to `display_info` can not be accessed, so `ftw` does exactly what it suppose to do - stops the traversal.

If you wish for it to continue, keep returning 0 even in those cases.

A better solution would be to use the newer, more advance function [`nftw`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ftw.3.html).

It will allow you to both specify flags to ignore dynamic links automatically, and also allow your callback function to specify different actions in case some items are not accessible.

For example, you could ask it to ignore children of inaccessible directories:

```
    case FTW_NS://stat failed
        return FTW_SKIP_SUBTREE;
    case FTW_DNR://read failed
        return FTW_SKIP_SUBTREE;
```

By default, in just about any Linux distribution, when you traverse from / some folders will be inaccessible, unless you run as root or use `sudo`.

Also, some files will not be real files, and you might want to take the opportunity to use `FTW_SKIP_SUBTREE` to skip folders such as `proc` and `dev`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try ftwn().

However returning 0 did not help: Operation not permitted.